# C++ Memory addresses?

Tags: c++, memory

How do memory addresses work?

In 32-bit a memory address is an hexadecimal value like 0x0F032010, right? But do those values point to bytes or to bits?

And what lies between two memory addresses like 0x0F032010 and 0x0F032011

Comment: Trust me my friend, for real understandin you WILL have to read some heavy books sooner or later. Four line answers from SOF are not going to get you farther ...
My fav OS book author : Tannenbaum.  Also You can start with Silberschatz, Galvin, Gagne

Comment: Nothing lies between two memory addresses, which is why doing pointer arithmetic with floating point values gives me compilation errors! grr!

Comment: Maybe a bunch of subatomic particles? :P

Comment: @Ajeet I'm joining Computer Science degree in October... Hopefully I will learn something in it regarding memory addresses ;D

Comment: Cool. One more brother joining us. :) 
Just a advise, start from basic books and then progress to other topics. Or else your mind will be swarming with millions of questions, and no matter how detailed answers you will see on SFO, they all will be like pieces of jig-saw puzzle,each one is correct, but you will not get the big picture correct. :)
All the best.

Comment: Memory address,which you saw, are 8 hexdecimal digit long.
Which means the size of the address is 4 bytes.
1. Memory address on some machines could be 8 bytes long(16 hex digits)
2. Size of integer or size of float and other variables are __independent__  of  size of address
3. On some machines size of address (pointer size), is 4 bytes only. It has to do with the databus address and size of the RAM of the machines.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie, dude, thats a typo. Corrected before I read your post. :) But thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In 32-bit a memory address is an hexadecimal value like 0x0F032010, right?

Its a number. A location in memory. It is bounded by the start and end of memory, which is starting at some value and ending at some value.

> But do those values point to bytes or to bits?

It is generally accepted that addresses point to the smallest addressable unit, which is a byte. Most modern CPUs are defined this way. This is however not always the case.

> And what lies between two memory addresses like 0x0F032010 and 0x0F032011

Dragons. Or nothing, as there isn't anything between them.

Answer (score 1):

In C and in C++, addresses ultimately point to something that is the same size as a `char` -- a "byte". That is the level of addressing in the language. Whether that truly is the level of addressing in the machine at hand is a different question. The number of bits in a byte is yet another question. The standard specifies a minimal value.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ (or C) address, or pointer value, is best thought of as pointing to an *object*, not (necessarily) to a byte.  Pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to object, so incrementing an `int*` value gives you a pointer to the adjacent `int` object (which might be, say, 4 bytes farther along in memory).

On the machine level, assuming a typical linear monolithic byte-addressed memory model, pointers are implemented as machine addresses, and each address is effectively a number that refers to a single byte.  An `int*` pointer value contains the address of the *first* byte of the `int` object it points to.  Incrementing a C++ `int*` pointer is implemented by adding `sizeof (int)` (say, 4) to the machine address.

As far as C++ is concerned, pointers are not integers; they're just pointers.  You can use casts to convert between pointer values and integer values, and the result *should* be meaningful in terms of the underlying machine's memory model, but not much is guaranteed about the results.  You can perform arithmetic on pointers, but on the language level that's not at all the same thing as integer arithmetic (though it's probably implemented as scaled integer arithmetic on the machine level).

The memory model I've described is not the only possible one, and both C and C++ are deliberately designed to allow other models.  For example, you could have a model where each individual object has its own memory space, and a pointer or address is a composite value consisting of something that identifies the object plus an offset within that object.  Given `int x; int y;`, you can compare their addresses for equality (`&x == &y` will be false), but the behavior of `&x < &y` is undefined; it's not even required that `&x < &y` and `&y < &x` have opposite values.

The C++ memory model works very nicely on top of a typical 32-bit flat memory model, and you *can* think of pointers as numbers.  But the C++ model is sufficiently abstract that it can also work on top of other models.

You can think about pointers and addresses either in the abstract terms defined by the language, or in the concrete terms implemented by the machine.  They're quite different, but ultimately compatible, mental models.  Keeping them both in your head simultaneously can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Those values are nothing in themselves, just numbers. A memory address is just a number that corresponds to a byte of memory, like the street address for your house. It's only a number.

The smallest unit an address can point to is a byte, so addresses point to bytes; you can think of the address pointing to the left side of your house; the actual house (the bits that make up the byte) is between your address (which points to the left side of your house) and your next door neighbor's address (pointing to the left side of his house). But there aren't any other addresses between there.